# Why do I get random numbers when using a joystick and an nRF24L01 module?

Tags: c, arduino

I'm trying to send code between an arduino nano and an arduino uno, the nano sending the values from a joystick held within a struct over to the uno. However, when the values are received, the numbers are seemingly random and make no sense. What is a potential solution to my code?

Transmitter

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;   
} joystick; 

#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24_config.h>

//Defining pins for later use
const int xAxis = A0; 
const int yAxis = A1;

//Object declaration 
RF24 radio(7, 8); // CE, CSN

joystick joy; 

//Address to use later
const uint64_t pipe = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL;

void setup() 
{
    radio.begin();
    radio.openWritingPipe(pipe);
    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
    //radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
    radio.stopListening(); 
  
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(xAxis, INPUT);
    pinMode(yAxis, INPUT); 
    delay(1000);
}

void loop() 
{
    int xInput = analogRead(xAxis);
    int yInput = analogRead(yAxis); 

    Serial.print("x-axis: ");
    Serial.print(xInput);
    Serial.print(" y-axis: ");
    Serial.println(yInput);
    
    joy.x = map(xInput, 0, 1023, 1100, 1900);
    joy.y = map(yInput, 0, 1023, 0, 180);
    
    radio.write(&joy, sizeof(joy));
    delay(50);
    
}
```

Receiver

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;   
} joystick; 

#include <Servo.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24_config.h>

//Defining pins for later use
const int EDFPin = 11;
const int servoPin = 6;

//Object declaration 
Servo edf;
Servo myServo; 

RF24 radio(9, 8); // CE, CSN

joystick joy; 

//Address to use later
const uint64_t pipe = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL;

void setup() 
{
    radio.begin();
    radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipe);
    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  //  radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS);
    radio.startListening(); 
  
    Serial.begin(9600);
    edf.attach(EDFPin);
    edf.writeMicroseconds(1500);
    myServo.attach(servoPin); 
    myServo.write(90);
    delay(1000);
}

void loop() 
{
    if (radio.available())
    {   
        while(radio.available())
        {
            radio.read(&joy, sizeof(joy)); 
            Serial.println(joy.x);
            Serial.println(joy.y);
            delay(50);
        }
     
    }

}
```

Comment: forget the joystick for a moment, can you send any data over the line and retrieve it? Wonder if there's noise on the serial line or something.

Comment: I was sending string before with random messages and receiving them fine, it's just when I turn to these numbers I start getting random numbers as opposed to what I actually am supposed to get.

Comment: Then I suspect @IbramReda is correct. Can you provide samples of the send and receive data you're getting? Sounds like `map` works differently than you expect it to. Have you tried sending a joystick without using `map`?

Answer (score 0):

Note that In transmitter, before you send the data  you make value Mapping for different range

```
joy.x = map(xInput, 0, 1023, 1100, 1900);
joy.y = map(yInput, 0, 1023, 0, 180);
```

This piece of code will make change in the values

1. Value of `joy.x` will be between the range [1100,1900]
2. The Value of `joy.y` will be between the range [0,180]

In transmitter, you print the original value  while in receiver you print the mapped value

if you need the original value in receiver send it directly without mapping like the following

```
joy.x = xInput;
joy.y = yInput;
```

read more about [map()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/) function